# Fitting a sinusoidal function to three known points

Tags: trigonometry

I have 3 points from a sine wave and I need to determine the sine function from this. 
There is a very similar question, but this question is with $-30°$, $0°$ and $+30°$: 
[Fitting a sinusoidal function to three known points separated by $30$ degrees](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450486/fitting-a-sinusoidal-function-to-three-known-points-separated-by-30-degrees?rq=1)

The only difference is that I have 3 points on 3 different random angles.

All help is wellcome, I haven't done this in 20 years. Thanks,

Emiel Peeters

Comment: The procedure in the accepted answer of that post works for arbitrary angles.

Answer (score 0):

In the other example you can scrap easily because the angles are -A and +A and 0. All my 3 angles are random ex: 10, 50 and 75 degrees.

Comment: This is better as a comment to the question, rather than an answer.